# How are linear constraints obtained?

Tags: operations-research

What is the process of writing linear constraints for the following for example?

> Let stocks be partitioned by capitalization: large, medium and small. 
>   We are looking for the portfolio to be divided evenly between large and medium cap stocks, and the investment in small cap stocks to be
>   between two and three times the investment in large cap stocks.

How would one start this off?

Any help is really appreciated. I will edit the post as I am making progress.

Comment: First, you need to introduce the decision variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the relevant pieces of information:

- "evenly between large and medium",
- "small between two and three times large".

This translates to $l=m,2l\le s\le 3l$.